# Decoding html in a scala template

Tags: templates, scala, playframework, html-escape-characters

I'm trying to make a tag that behaves differently based on the route, but when I try to render html within a `@{ ... }` block, I can't seem to insert my variables correctly.

```
@(route: String, on_image: String, off_image: String, alt_text: String)

@{
    val Pattern = ("(" + route + ".*)").r
    val path = request().path()


    path match {
        case Pattern(foo) => {
            if(path != route && route == "/") {
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    alert("{route}");
                </script>
            } else {
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    alert("{route}");
                </script>           
            }
        }
        case _ => {
            <script type="text/javascript">
                alert("{route}");
            </script>       
        }
    }
}
```

When I load the page, I get a syntax error in my Firebug console, where it's revealed that the content of the script tag evaluated to this:

`alert(&quot;/accounts&quot;);`

Now, I've tried things like `@Html{ ... }` and `@Html( ... )` and `@Html({ ... })` surrounding the whole block. I've also tried `alert(@Html("{bar}"));` and other similar things, but everything produces various errors.

What's the right way to do this?

**Edit**

Updated to show trying to use only one variable for simplicity's sake, and showing where that variable comes from.

Comment: where is bar coming from? assuming it is somewhere in the code too, have you tried @ foo and @ bar inside the quotes instead of {foo} ?

Comment: That's actually a step backwards. Then I get `&quot;@foo&quot;`

Comment: In any case, the problem is with the quotes, not with what's inside them. You can see from the output that I posted in my question that {foo} (or actually, {route}) returns the value. I need to get that value into a javascript string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved with a little indirection.

```
@(route: String, on_image: String, off_image: String, alt_text: String)

@on = {
    <a href="@route"><img src="@routes.Assets.at(on_image)" alt="@alt_text" /></a>
}

@off = {
    <a href="@route"><img src="@routes.Assets.at(off_image)" alt="@alt_text" /></a>
}

@{
    val Pattern = ("(" + route + ".*)").r
    val path = request().path()


    path match {
        case Pattern(foo) => {
            if(path != route && route == "/") {
                {off}
            } else {
                {on}    
            }
        }
        case _ => {
            {off}       
        }
    }
}
```